# Pretty date js is not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, date

I am using pretty date js which show date objects as social way like "2 min ago", "5 days ago" etc. But although it works on chrome it is not working on firefox and cause I am javascript newbiew I cant figure out why. Get the code from J.Resig page and modified to my needs.

Here is the code

```
// Takes an ISO time and returns a string representing how
// long ago the date represents.
function prettyDate(time){
    var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
        diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
        day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

    if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31 )
        return;

    return day_diff == 0 && (
            diff < 60 && "şimdi" ||
            diff < 120 && "1 dk önce" ||
            diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " dk önce" ||
            diff < 7200 && "1 saat önce" ||
            diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " saat önce") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "Dün" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " gün önce" ||
        day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " hafta önce";
}

// Takes an ISO time and returns a string representing how
// long later the date represents.
function prettyReverseDate(time){
    var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
        diff = (( date.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime() ) / 1000),
        day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

    //console.log("Day dif : " + day_diff);

    if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31 )
        return ;

    //put what ever string you wanted like "Expirs in # hour/minute/day"
    return day_diff == 0 && (
            diff < 60 && " şimdi" ||
            diff < 120 && " 1 dk" ||
            diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " dakika" ||
            diff < 7200 && " 1 saat" ||
            diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " saat") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "1 gün" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " gün" ||
        day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " hafta";
}

// If jQuery is included in the page, adds a jQuery plugin to handle it as well
if ( typeof jQuery != "undefined" )
    jQuery.fn.prettyDate = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var date = prettyDate(this.title);
            if ( date )
                jQuery(this).text( date );
            else
                jQuery(this).text("n/a");
        });
    };

// If jQuery is included in the page, adds a jQuery plugin to handle it as well
if ( typeof jQuery != "undefined" )
    jQuery.fn.prettyReverseDate = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var date = prettyReverseDate(this.title);
            if ( date )
                jQuery(this).text( date );
            else
                //make parent element show expired
                jQuery(this).parent().text("süresi doldu");
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all use the **Firebug addon** for Firefox to execute the code
or to show the error message which occurs during the execution.

When I just copy and paste your "prettyReverseDate" function a syntax error shows up.

Debug your code with Firebug until you see no error messages.
Then examine the actual code logic.

Firebug documentation: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Sure I am using firebug but it did not show up error to me its a little weird. I am using version 11 of Firefox on linux. May be you can help me with the error you have found.

Comment: prettyDate works in FF I've used it in the past, you need to work on your javascript skills and learn how to use Firebug for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem related to time format that prettyReverse and pretty function taking and it has additional part which starts with "." After removing that part with split function problem gone.

```
var date = new Date( ( ( time || "" ).replace( /-/g,"/" ).replace( /[TZ]/g," " ) ).split( '.' )[0] ),
```